# Testing Sparkpost SMTP RELAY

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer, sparkpost

Ok I am using Yii2 mailer, but I need to test access to sparkpost smtp on regular bases. So I made an action that sends a email to Sparkpost when I call it.

Now Is there a way to tell Sparkpost that this email is just a test so it will not send the email? I need this so I would not send hundreds of mails a day to sparkpost just for testing purposes.

NOTE: I am using simple SMTP Relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to not have an email actually get delivered from SparkPost is to append ".sink.sparkpostmail.com" to the end of the email address. For instance, if your email address is "alice@example.com" then use "alice@example.com.sink.sparkpostmail.com"

You can find more details about that here:
    https://www.sparkpost.com/docs/faq/using-sink-server/